# Converting a linear linked list to a circular linked list

Tags: c, list

I have a few questions for the following piece of code. Please bear with me. The code might be easy to understand, but I am still in the process of learning, so this is still abstract to me.

```
struct listNode {
int data;
struct listNode *next };

//Is J a pointer, pointing to the head of the linked list?
struct listNode * convert ( struct listNode * J) {

if (J == NULL) 
    return NULL; 

//Is this creating a new temporary pointer that will traverse the linked list?
//Is it being set to J so that it can start at the first node and go to the last?
struct listNode * temp = J; 

while ( temp -> next != NULL) 
    temp = temp->next; //Is this where the temp pointer actually goes through the list?

//Temp->next will eventually become the last node of the list and that will be set to J
//which is the head pointer?
  temp->next = J; 

return temp;
}
```

Comment: My questions are in the comments

Comment: explained in a more simpler way, please check

Comment: try putting in some whitespace to better associate your in-line comment/questions with the line of code it refers to.  Whitespace is your friend! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Everything you wrote as comments is true, and at the end you can consider any point as `head` since it's a circular list now*

the only difference between a linear linked list and a circular one is that the last node points to NULL in the first case, or it points to the first node, for the second.

The algorithm:

**1)** you take a `temp` pointer to find the last node (initialise it with `J`, the head, and parse the list until you hit NULL)

**2)** you point `temp`, which is the last node now, to the first node, which is `J`